# May I shuffle the order of the e-mails in a response for a FETCH command?

Tags: imap

If the client does a FETCH with a range of sequence numbers, must the server response give each e-mail in ascending sequence number order?

The RFC3501 contains the following example of a FETCH command.

```
C: A654 FETCH 2:4 (FLAGS BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM)])
S: * 2 FETCH ....
S: * 3 FETCH ....
S: * 4 FETCH ....
S: A654 OK FETCH completed
```

Would the following example represent a compliant server?

```
C: A654 FETCH 2:4 (FLAGS BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE FROM)])
S: * 3 FETCH ....
S: * 4 FETCH ....
S: * 2 FETCH ....
S: A654 OK FETCH completed
```

I could not find nothing in the sections for FETCH request and FETCH response regarding the order of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder as much as you want. The paragraph Paurian quotes applies to UID assignment, not to reporting.

It's also safe in practice: Symantec's IMAP proxy (I forget its name, but its job is to scan for naughty attachments and present a santised view of the world to IMAP clients) sends `fetch` responses in an unpredictable order, and the main developer knows about no problems resulting from that.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, No. The sequence must be in order. [See comments, below - as the specs mention storage, not retrieval of order.]

> 2.3.1.1.        Unique Identifier (UID) Message Attribute
>
> A 32-bit value assigned to each message, which when used with the
> unique identifier validity value (see below) forms a 64-bit value
> that MUST NOT refer to any other message in the mailbox or any
> subsequent mailbox with the same name forever.  Unique identifiers
> are assigned in a strictly ascending fashion in the mailbox; as each
> message is added to the mailbox it is assigned a higher UID than the
> message(s) which were added previously.  **Unlike message sequence
>
> numbers, unique identifiers are not necessarily contiguous.**

Since these are sequence numbers, the result must be contiguous.

Articld 6.4.8. implies that FETCH without the UID prefix indicates a sequence search rather than a unique identifier within your range expression:

> ```
>   ... the UID command (variant) takes a SEARCH command with
>   SEARCH command arguments.  The interpretation of the arguments is
>   the same as with SEARCH; however, the numbers returned in a SEARCH
>   response for a UID SEARCH command are unique identifiers instead
> ```

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501

Comment: Contiguous in this case just means how they are assigned.  There must be no holes in sequence numbers.  I don't believe there are any requirements in the order the server responds to a FETCH or Search.  Ascending is common, but not required.

Comment: Very good point. I dug around other boards and found that someone else had a similar question about shuffling the sequence order. It sounds like an email server was reordering based on UID and didn't seem to cause any issues (Source: http://mailman13.u.washington.edu/pipermail/imap-protocol/2014-April/002247.html ) ... the takeaway is that people are expecting FETCH to return sequence ordered results, but should accomodate a mixed sequence if they're writing a client.